# Conditional Selecting of child elements in pdfquery

Tags: python

I am using pdfquery to extract data from PDF.
My pdf tree xml looks like following:

```
<LTTextLineHorizontal>
  <LTTextBoxHorizontal>Address</LTTextBoxHorizontal>
</LTTextLineHorizontal>

<LTTextBoxHorizontal>
  <LTTextBoxHorizontal>
     First-Name
  </LTTextBoxHorizontal>
  <LTTextBoxHorizontal>
     Last-Name
  </LTTextBoxHorizontal>
</LTTextBoxHorizontal>
```

The idea is  to make a string that is **Address First-Name Last-Name**

The need then arises to select child elements depending on their existence, i am at a loss on how to do it.

Comment: Any luck with the solution I posted below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `.extract` with the `with_parents` keyword in order to extract the children. The documentation gives a [decent example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfquery#with-parent)

```
pdf.extract([
     ('with_parent','LTPage[page_index="1"]'),
     ('last_name', ':in_bbox("315,680,395,700")')
 ])
```

In this case, you're simply limiting the search to page 1 of the document. However, you can also pass in the result of previous selections with the `with_parent` keyword.

For example, if, in your example, Address had children (street, city, zipcode), you could first find the address section, store the element as a variable and then us `.extract` to pull out the children. How you store and structure the resulting data will depend on your ultimate needs.

address = pdf.pdfquery('LTTextBoxHorizontal:contains("Address")')

```
pdf.extract([
    ('with_parent', address),
    (..., ...)])
```

In many cases, the children are not necessarily nested within the xml tree and you need to resort to bbox based approach. What I do in that case is construct a bbox using the "parent" as the top boundary and the next known non-child as the bottom boundary and then pass that in to `.extract`. Just remember that bboxes are constructed with the bottom-left, top-right coordinates.